# Junit to test if the method call is made

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I've a transaction class with a validate method. There is a condition in the method that when satisfied will not be calling an alert notification method, which, on the other hand, will only be called when the check condition failed (if condition is false, call the alert and notify the user).
I want to test with a JUnit, if that alert method get's called or not. Could someone advise how to proceed, as I'm new to JUnits.

Answer (score 4):

Look at mocking libraries. In Mockito it will be like

```
    Notifier mock = Mockito.mock(Notifier.class); 
    ClassUnderTest myClass = new ClassUnderTest(mock);
    myClass.doSomething(-1);
    Mockito.verify(mock).notification(Mockito.eq("Negative value passed!"));
    myClass.doSomething(100);
    Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(mock);
```

Comment: To clarify, `Mockito.verify(mock).close();` is what tests that the method was called.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. so I should be having the condition in my Junit method and then call the method from within the condition and mock the method call?

Comment: I hope my example should shed more light.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) framework. This framework makes your kind of testing much easier.

You can use the `verify` method:

```
//Check if called once
verify(dependency, times(1)).yourMethod()
```

Check the API for more [informations](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.10.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html).

Comment: This is not really an answer as is. Why don't you add the mockito code for verifying that a method is called and I'll give you a +1.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it is not clear whether or not the alert notification method belongs to the same class you are testing.

If the alert notification method is *in a different class* than the method you are testing, you can use a mocking library like Mockito to verify the method call, as suggested by other answers.

If, on the other hand, the notification method is *in the same class* as the validation method, I would advice to not verify the call to the notification method, but to verify the *output* of this method (you probably want to use a mocking library for this as well, but to verify method calls on any other objects used to create the alert)

A third possibility is that both methods are in the same class, but you really only want to test that the notification method gets called and not its output, because you feel that notification is a different function that you want to test separately. This would be a sign that your class may be doing too many things, and that it may be best to refactor so that these methods end up in separate classes.

Comment: yes the method is in another class (not in the method for which I'll be writing the test case)

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this myself in this late age of 2021. But I found an easy way to validate that a mock is called that doesn't require additional libraries. I'm not sure it's "correct", it doesn't feel exactly "correct", but it's adequate for my needs.

```
// test/org/mycompany/MyScriptTests.groovy
// testing vars/MyScript.groovy

import org.junit.*
import com.lesfurets.jenkins.unit.*
import static groovy.test.GroovyAssert.*

class MyScriptTests extends BasePipelineTest {
  def MyScript

  @Before
  void setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    
    // set up mocks
    helper.registerAllowedMethod('functionToMock', [<param type>], { return 'a validation string' } )

    // load MyScript
    MyScript = loadScript("vars/MyScript.groovy")
  }

  @Test
  void aTest() {
    // set up mocks
    def myparam = 'myparam'

    // call MyScript and check result
    def result = MyScript(myparam)
    assert 'a validation string'.equals(result)

  }
```